# NSString boundingRect with image glyphs included within UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm attempting to determine the appropriate height a UILabel will need when constrained to a max width with NSAttributedString for the label.

The problem I'm running into is the height calculation is off when I include a small image at the end of the UILabel.

Here is what I'm doing.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *fullName;

// Append the First and Last Name
NSMutableAttributedString *fullName = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName] attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : fontColor }];

// Append image
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"starImage"];   
NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
[fullName appendAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];

// Set the label AttributedText
self.fullName.attributedText = fullName;
```

Later I call a helper method to determine the height this fullName label will need.

```
- (CGFloat)heightOfLabel:(UILabel *)label withMaxWidth:(CGFloat)width {
   CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX);
   return [label.text boundingRectWithSize:boundingSize
                                   options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}
                                   context:nil].size.height;
}
```

This is where the problem is as the small image I append isn't taken into account. I've even tried `label.attributedText` instead of `label.text` with no result.

Any thoughts or suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context: doesn't work, but the much simpler size method does. This does take into account the size of the image.

```
CGSize *stringSize = fullName.size;
```

Comment: It doesn't work if we want to constraint UILabel's dimension, like compute the height with specific width.